# Access model without foreach

Tags: php

If its possible to access the '`entry_id`' data in a `foreach` loop as below, if I know there is only one item, is there a better way to access it?

```
$arr = array();

foreach( $order->items as $item ) {
    $arr[] = $item->entry_id;
}
```

Comment: `if(count($order->items)>1){foreach( $order->items as $item ) {
        $arr[] = $item->entry_id;
    }}else{$arr[] = $order->items[0]->entry_id;};`

Comment: What does `$order->items` look like exactly...?!

Comment: if you are sure there is only one element, you can make that : $order->items[0]->entry_id;

Comment: show us `$order` data?

Comment: Actually... why would you have a multidimensional array and then care for the special case of *one item*? Either `$order->items` is designed to contain multiple items, in which case you should probably always treat it as if it does, or `$order->items` holds one element, in which case it shouldn't be an array and it should be named `$order->item`. In what scenario do you need to treat the special case of 1 differently?

Comment: Well using the foreach, even if there is only one item, won't be a problem. It will iterate trough the only item and apply the values. It's better since it works for both arrays (with single or multiple items)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If order->items is **no-associative** array and its only 1 element, you can access it this way:

```
echo $order->items[0]->entry_id;
```

But more safe will be check how many items in array:

```
if(count($order->items) > 0)
    echo $order->items[0]->entry_id;
```

Comment: *Assuming* the items are zero-indexed... (likely, but unknown at this point)